# The onRefresh callback returned null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `RefreshIndicator` to refresh data from the internet, but when I pulled down from the top, the refresh icon didn't disappear, also an error occured:

```
════════ Exception caught by material library ══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown when calling onRefresh:
The onRefresh callback returned null.

The RefreshIndicator onRefresh callback must return a Future.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Here's my code where the method to get data is declared:

```
Future<void> getApiData() async {
  return fetchWorldData();
}

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchWorldData() async {
  Response response = await get(Uri.parse(
      'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${CurrentCountry.currentcountry}'));
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

And here's my code where the method is called:

```
onRefresh: () {
  getApiData();
}
```

If you can help me, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

It will return null as you didn't put `await` here so it immediately returns the result (not waiting for API to get the actual data)
So do it like this

```
onRefresh: () async {
  await getApiData();
}
```

Comment: The error disappeared but the data shown in the UI still doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function is calling your function, but not actually returning it's result.

You could do:

```
onRefresh: () {
  return getApiData();
}
```

or even shorter:

```
onRefresh: () => getApiData()
```

or since your signatures match *exactly*, just

```
onRefresh: getApiData
```